# jquery append(); создается несколько элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь перетащить элемент с 1 блока в другой в зависимости от ширины экрана. При неоднократном вызове функции элементы скапливаются и вместо 1 добавляются по нарастающей. Как поправить? На локальном сервере все работает хорошо, после залива в инет глючит.

```
function sizesLink() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: " + mediaMd + "px)").matches) {
            if ( !($('.sizes-container').is(':has(.sizes-link)')) ) {
                $('.sizes-container').append($('.sizes-link'));
            }
        } else {
            if ( !($('.st-wrapper').is(':has( > .sizes-link)')) ) {
                $('.st-wrapper').append($('.sizes-link'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: а где удаление старого элемента ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перед добавлением нового элемента, чистить блок от старого.

```
$(".st-wrapper").html("");
```